# how to get id based on value of objects and set into another object - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are two array of objects and i want to filter two values by iterating differently to get two different id.

**Here is the example**

```
1st array :  list_of_products: [ { text: "Shoes", value: 1},{text:"Clothing", value: 2},{text:"Foods", value: 3}]

2nd Array:   list_of_names: [{ text: "jim" , value: 1},{text:"Sim", value: 2},{text:"Tim",value:3}]
```

Now, i want to get the ids by filtering out two arrays based on names like this

```
product_name: "Clothing", person_name:"Tim"
```

Then i want to store the ids like this

```
const newIds = { product_id: 2,name_id: 3}
```

This i have tried:

```
const newProduct_name = list_of_products.find(name => name.text === product_name);
 const newName = list_of_names.find(name => name.text === person_name);

storing it into new object like this 
  const values = {product_id: newProduct_name.value ,name_id: newName.value}
```

How to do this by minimal use of variables and faster execution?

Comment: I have updated my code. Is there any workaround make it more concise and faster?

Comment: Do you need to do this often, or for many items? If so  creating a Map or object at beginning for each array would make lookups far more efficient

Comment: yes there are many items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating Maps or objects using the lookup values as keys lets you iterate each of your source arrays once and then have o(1) searches rather than using `find()` to iterate each array many times

```js
const products= [ { text: "Shoes", value: 1},{text:"Clothing", value: 2},{text:"Foods", value: 3}],
names= [{ text: "jim" , value: 1},{text:"Sim", value: 2},{text:"Tim",value:3}];


const createMap = (arr) => new Map(arr.map(o => [o.text, o.value])),  
      prodMap = createMap(products),
      namesMap = createMap(names);

const data = [{
  product_name: "Clothing",
  person_name: "Tim"
}];

const res = data.map(o => {
  return {
    product_id: prodMap.get(o.product_name),
    name_id: namesMap.get(o.person_name)
  };
})

console.log(res)
```